# Sets and ArrayLists

Tags: java, arraylist, set

If I have an ArrayList of object type and I want to get the name of a particular object I would use

```
arraylist.get(i).getName();
```

But it does not work with Sets? How do I call the particular attribute using Sets?

Also reason I am trying to do this is because Im handling a lot of data. How much more efficient

are Sets?

Comment: A `Set` is not a datastructre for retrieving elements by index, since they have no order.

Comment: Can it contain objects?

Comment: Sets don't provide order, but uniqueness.

Comment: @hat_to_the_back what do you mean?? Or course it can contain objects. But is has no index and no order so getting the nth element would make very little sense.

Comment: Ok then how to you retrieve a particular element from the set?

Comment: You iterate into it until you find it. If you want uniqueness based on key, use a Map. If you want a list, use a list.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to grab particular elements then an array/arraylist is a better implementation. Though if you really need to you sets you could itterate through the set with a for loop, like:

```
for(MyObject elem : mySet){
  elem.getName();//Do something with each name
}
```

To grab each name.

Answer (score 1):

A List (ArrayList) is indicated if

- the order of the list elements matters
- if multiple instances of equal elements are to be inserted
- you can (reasonably) access elements using the index values 0, 1, 2,...
- fast iteration over all values is important

A Set (HashSet) is preferable if

- each instance of equal elements should be represented only once
- you don't care about insertion order
- you don't need to retrieve by an index (or some other property)

To access a property of the elements in a Set, you can (or have to) iterate over the Set elements (in no particular order) and call the getter:

```
Set<Element> setOfEl = ...;

for( Element el: setOfEl ){
    if( el.getName().equals( ... ){
        //....
    }
```

.    }

Comment: If I am iterating through an arraylist or a set which is faster?

Comment: The ArrayList is backed by an array and this is faster.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with `getName()` but with getting the object on which you call `getName()`. In the case of an ArrayList, you can call `get(i)` to get the i-th element. In the case of a set, no such order is defined.

You have two choices. Either you define it as a `Map` and you call `get(<yourkey>)` and then call getName(), or you iterate through the set until you find what you are looking for using `.iterator()`

Comment: So say I want to compare string elements of one arraylist to that of the Set how do I loop through the set?

Comment: `for(Element element : setName) { System.out.println(element.getName()); }`

Answer (score 0):

`ArrayList<E>`, as the name says, is a `List<E>`, hence the method `get(i)` gives you an object of type `E`. 
`Set<E>` do not have such method hence `getName()` will not work.

`Set<E>` is not ordered. You have to use an Iterator to parse a Set and traverse all of its elements.

You can refer to the [documentation here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Set.html):